# Elapsed time between two timestamps

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm having real trouble converting two timestamps into elapsed time in seconds for example:

07/16/2015  14:01:42:140
07/16/2015 14:01:52:563

I have tried multiple functions and the classic (A3-A2) trick, but nothing seems to output the elapsed time in seconds and milliseconds. I could really use some guidance.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of a `:`, use a `.` to separate the milliseconds.

```
07/16/2015 14:01:42.140 
07/16/2015 14:01:05.563
```

Then just subtract the two as normal. You may need to set the number format to something like this to stop Excel from cutting off the milliseconds.

```
mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.000
```

Comment: ...and if your data already includes the semi-colon between seconds and milliseconds you can use SUBSTITUTE function within the formula to convert, e.g. `=SUBSTITUTE(A3,":",".",3)-SUBSTITUTE(A2,":",".",3)` - format result cell as [s].000 to see just seconds and milliseconds